# Retrieve passwords from "pass" which are stored under the name of a folder

Tags: linux, passwords, password-management

I'm very new to [pass](https://www.passwordstore.org) and some days ago I inserted a lot of passwords into it.

Suppose you store passwords under `test` and `test/abc`.

What I noticed is, that it **seems to be impossible** to "show" the password stored under `test`, because `pass` then only shows the `tree` of the passwords under that name.

```
foo@bar:~$ pass insert test
Enter password for test: 
Retype password for test: 
foo@bar:~$ pass insert test/abc
Enter password for test/abc: 
Retype password for test/abc: 
foo@bar:~$ pass test
test
└── abc
foo@bar:~$ pass show test
test
└── abc
foo@bar:~$ pass show test/abc
112233
```

Does anyone know how to retrieve this password? Is it a bug?

Thanks.

**Edit**

I found the [git commit, which solves this issue](https://git.zx2c4.com/password-store/commit/src/password-store.sh?id=0d9c02562ea5792fdf9691135a2b48f667a4c97d). The version of pass from the Ubuntu repository is way too old.

Comment: Some variation of `for entry in $(pass show test); do pass show test/$entry; done` might get you started. (It won't work as-is, but it shouldn't be too hard to turn into something workable.)

Comment: Sorry, but I think you misunderstood my question. My problem ist getting the one password stored unter `test` and not all password there.

Comment: Oh. Yes, I did misunderstand your question then. Surely there are command line parameters intended for that scenario; have you looked over the man page and the output of `pass --help`, `pass -?` or any similar variations?

Comment: Yes, it clearly says that you can retrieve passwords with `pass <name>` or `pass show <name>`. Maybe I should take a look at the source, just thought I missed something.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling Thanks for your efforts. After university I had time to investigate further and found out, that the version from the Ubuntu repo is way too old. The commit I added to the question fixes this issue.

Comment: You shouldn't edit your question for that. See https://superuser.com/help/self-answer.

Comment: Oops, did not want to chat ;) Ok, thanks for the tip. Then I have to wait. Or you want to get some rep ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the [git commit, which solves this issue](https://git.zx2c4.com/password-store/commit/src/password-store.sh?id=0d9c02562ea5792fdf9691135a2b48f667a4c97d).

The version of pass from the Ubuntu repository is way too old.